# Elasticsearch query range last 15min

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to create a simple query to return matching deploymentId from the documents in index logstash.

I'm able to search match query but when adding time range getting following exemption.

Error:

> "type" : "parsing_exception",
> "reason" : "[match] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",

I want only the last 15 min records matching the deploymentId.

```
GET /logstash-dev-2021.12.03/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "deploymentId" : "64a5d214-368c-4760"
    }, 
    "range": {
      "time": {
        "gte": "now-15m",
        "lte": "now"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can use `range` and `match` in the same query,

You could try to use a boolean query.

```
GET /logstash-dev-2021.12.03/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "range": {
            "time": {
              "gte": "now-15m",
              "lte": "now"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "deploymentId" : "64a5d214-368c-4760"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Paulo, It is working, but not able to get the hit count.

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.16/search-your-data.html#track-total-hits

Comment: Hi @RamaKrishnaS could you accept the answer if it did solve your issue ?